# Clicks in queue buffers OpenAL

Tags: c++, boost-asio, openal

My program isn't working right. I need to play sound which i take from network with boost::asio. That sound is right, because if I give that to file, i have sound file. But in speakers I listen repeating clicks. That is my code:

```
while (!ExitKey)
{
    boost::system::error_code error;
    size_t len = VoiceSocket->read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buf), error);
    if (len==0)
    {
        continue;
    }
    file.write(buf.data(), 882);
    if (firstit++>=3)
    {
        alSourceUnqueueBuffers(alSource, 1, &alUnqueueBuf);
    }
    if (iteration <=3)
    {
        alBufferData(alSampleSet[iteration++], AL_FORMAT_MONO16, buf.data(), buf.size(), 44100);
    }
    else
    {
        iteration = 0;
        alBufferData(alSampleSet[iteration++], AL_FORMAT_MONO16, buf.data(), buf.size(), 44100);
    }
    //alSourceQueueBuffers(alSource, 3, alSampleSet);
    alSourcei(alSource, AL_BUFFER, alSampleSet[0]);
    alSourcei(alSource, AL_BUFFER, alSampleSet[1]);
    alSourcei(alSource, AL_BUFFER, alSampleSet[2]);

    alSourceQueueBuffers(alSource, 1, alSampleSet);
    //
    //alSourcei(alSource, AL_LOOPING, alSampleSet);
    ALenum alErr0 = AL_NO_ERROR;
    ALenum alErr1 = AL_INVALID_NAME;
    ALenum alErr2 = AL_INVALID_ENUM;
    ALenum alErr3 = AL_INVALID_VALUE;
    ALenum alErr4 = AL_INVALID_OPERATION;
    ALenum alErr5 = AL_OUT_OF_MEMORY;
    ALenum alErr  = alGetError();
    //alGetSourcei(alSource, AL_SOURCE_STATE, &alErr);
    alSourcePlay(alSource);
    alErr = alGetError();
    //
}
```

Please help me. What I need to do with this code to get it work. I dont understand how working with this buffers :(

Answer (score 0):

You should use either `alSourcei(alSource, AL_BUFFER, alSampleSet[0])` or `alSourceQueueBuffers(alSource, 1, alSampleSet)`, but not both together. When you are streaming, then use the latter.

Check for processed buffers before unqueueing:

```
alGetSourcei(alSource, AL_BUFFERS_PROCESSED, out p)
```

Only buffer and queue the next chunk if there is a free buffer.